# Is there a way to make custom composition guides?

Tags: camera

I found this:
https://blenderartists.org/t/custom-composition-guides/597819
but it requires to modify the existing ones in ‘C’.

Second option would be to make some with actual geometry.

You'd think that in 2018 there would be a more user friendly way to do this.

Is there ?

Comment: There is one more option. Background image with the lines you need.

Comment: I'm trying to do some camera matching for a blender + real-world photo -- the final product must be square. My digital camera's highest res photos are 4240x2832 (about 1.5 aspect ratio). It sure would be nice to have a 'middle square' composition guide in my camera.